# select con subquery dos base de datos mysql node

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs, typescript

Como puedo hacer la siguiente consulta

```
"select * 
from table2 A
Where Not exists (select 1 from table1 B Where A.ID = B.value)"
```

teniendo en cuenta que la tabla B es una base de datos con diferente conexion.

```
let sql = `select * from compania `;
config1.query(sql, (error, results, fields) => {
  if (error) {
    return console.error(error.message);
  }


   setValue(results)
  //console.log(results_mi_portal);
});

config1.end(); 

console.log("******************************************************************************");
let sql_pivotal = `select * from compania WHERE not=? `;

config.query(sql_pivotal, resutSql, (error, results, fields) => {

  if (error) {
    return console.error(error.message);
  }
  console.log(results);
});

config.end();
```

como se debe realizar esta consulta para las dos bds

Comment: Si ambas tablas se encuentra en el mismo servidor se puede comparar con una consulta. Pero con conexiones que son totalmente distintas tendrás que consultar tus tablas individualmente y por programacíon hacer el match de tus datos.